# react-sortable-hoc. onClick event on <SortableElement/>

Tags: reactjs

```
 const SortableItem = SortableElement(({ i, value}) =>
            <ListItem button   onClick={this.handleClick(i, value.title)}>
                <ListItemText primary={<div className={classes.title}>{value.title}</div>}/>
            </ListItem>
    );
```

when I call this SortableItem in SortableContainer and then in render use it, when clicking on one item it call the handleClick function for all  elements the same time. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Call click event like this.

```
<ListItem button   onClick={()=> this.handleClick(i, value.title)}>
```

Comment: I tried this case, but it was not working, now it do not call handleClick.

Comment: how about `{(e)=> {this.handleClick(i, value.title)}}`

Comment: handleClick = (index, value) => {
        console.log(index, value);
    };

Comment: {(e)=> {this.handleClick(i, value.title)}} this does not help too

Answer (score 0):

I made the div with the onClick as a button, and onClick worked,

Spent a lot of time figuring it out, There is no need to use distance or pressDelay
[image]